Two cases of flex containers with and without vertical overflowing


html {
  height: 50%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item-1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item-2 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">
    <div class="item-2">
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
      <span>Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



There is content inside .item-2 whose height is more than that .container has. To prevent vertical overflowing I set min-height: 0; and overflow: auto; to its parent .item-1.
And that seemingly works. .container and .item-1 share the same height, and item-2 has that corresponding to its content overflowing the parent with the scroll functionality provided.
However, why if we bring those properties from .item-1 to .item-2 the picture will become different? I mean in this case, .item-1 will get the .item-2 height value then overflow .container and there will be no scroll bar.
How are these two cases different?

because item-1 is overflowing, item-2 is not (and you don't need to set min-height:0, setting overflow is enough)

@TemaniAfif why .item-1 gets the height of .container, not that of its content (.item-2) (the first case), but .item-2, oppositely, follows its own content (a bulk of spans) (the second case)?

add min-height:0 or overflow: auto to item-2 as well and it will also get the height of its parent BUT if you don't do this on item-1 nothing will happen because in that case item-2 is fine (not overflowing and taking its content height)

@TemaniAfif nothing will happen because in that case item-2 is fine - is it because .item-1 has no height value defined (in contrast with .container)?

@TemaniAfif it's the essence of my question, in fact. Setting overflow: auto; to .item-1 is enough to it not to follow its content's height, setting the same property to  .item-2 is not enough. So, what's the diffrence?

you basically answered your own question. if item-1 is following its content's height then nothing will happen with item-2 because you have no overflow issue at item-2 if item-1 is following its content's height.

Although the default value for min-height / min-width property is 0, elements in a flexbox container without overflow property will have its min-width or min-height (depends on flex-direction) set to be auto.
In your scenario, min-height of item-2 is auto if there's no overflow property in item-1, which is equivalent to the size of the children.
Specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto
